# C++: Find any element from container1 not in container2

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, std

I have a `std::set<int>` (s) and a `std::vector<int>` (v). The vector is guaranteed to be sorted/unique. I want to know if all elements of v are in s (or just stop at the first element of v not in s). I could convert v into a set and do == test, but is there another way without changing the container type?

Comment: A loop, `std::find_if()` and a lambda?

Comment: How about `std::mismatch`?

Comment: `std::set_difference`?

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted; it's a clear, reasonable and useful question.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at docs of `std::mismatch`. That would only work because my vector is sorted right? Is my understanding correct? `std::set_difference` should work well as it takes two sorted ranges. Didn't realize you didn't have to give 2 set containers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's about [std::includes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) algorithm?

Here's a short usage example:

```
vector<int> v1 { 1, 2, 4, 8 };
vector<int> v2 { 1, 2, 3, 8 };
set<int> s { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 };
cout << includes(s.begin(), s.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end()) << endl;
cout << includes(s.begin(), s.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end()) << endl;
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `std::set::count` or `std::unordered_set::count`:

```
if( v.size() > s.size() )
{
    // since v has unique values
    // v is not subset of s
    // if you need to find a first element of v not in s
    // you need to run the loop below anyway
}
for( auto i : v )
{
    if( !s.count( i ))
    {
        // i not in s
    }
}
```

If you need all elements of v not in s, just use `std::set_difference`

Comment: That's O(n log m), but the other options suggested are O(n + m), which is better.

Comment: Can we assume s is std::unordered_set? Then, it's O(n)

Comment: True, although OP specified `set`.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::set<int>` will be ordered. If the `std::vector<int>` is guaranteed to be ordered and contain unique values, you can iterate over both of them and compare the values of the items.

```
std::set<int> s = {...};
std::vector<int> v = {...};

// Default answer. If v.size() > s.size(), the answer is
// definitely false. Otherwise, assume the answer to be true.
bool ans = ( v.size() <= s.size() );

auto si = s.begin();
auto vi = v.begin();

// We need to check for si != s.end()
for ( ; ans == true && vi != v.end() && si != s.end(); ++si )
{
    if ( *si == *vi ) ++vi;
    else if ( *si > *vi ) ans = false;
}
if ( vi != v.end() ) ans = false;
// ...
return ans;
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n) solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

bool incCase(std::set<int> &s, std::vector<int> &v)
{
    if( v.size() > s.size())
        return false;

    auto si = s.begin();

    for(int& vv : v)
    {
        for(;;si++)
        {
            if(si==s.end() || *si>vv)
                return false;
            if(*si==vv)
            {
                si++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 };
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > vv { 
        { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 },
        { 0, 2 },
        { 4, 16 },
        { 2, 8, },
        { 4},
        { 1, 4, 16 },
        { 0, 2, 8},
        { },
        { -1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 32 },
        { 0, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 16 },
        { 3, 8, },
        { 5},
        { 1, 5, 16 },
        { 0, 3, 8},
    };

    int i = 1;
    for(auto &v : vv)
    {
        std::cout<< i++ << (incCase(s,v)?" = True":" = False") << std::endl;
    }
}
```